# ISETool.exe and all IsolatedStorage Explorer Tools suddenly stopped working -> "SmartDevice.Connectivity.DeviceNotFoundException"

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am currently on the edge of madness with regards to the IsolatedStorage Explorer Tools. I've been using http://isostorespy.codeplex.com/ for a month now without any problems but today it just suddenly stopped working. After a bit of research I found that the command line version "ISETool.exe" also crashes without any explanation (see Screenshot)

[image]

I am using Windows 8.1 Pro x64. Does anyone know what is going on with this and how I can fix it?

Comment: Are you using windows phone 8.1 on your device. I think i also faced this today. i just removed my device , replugged it and tried again when the debugger was not running.

Comment: Sadly this is not working. Also i am using windows phone 8.0